# C# MS Chart slow on large amount of real-time data

Tags: c#, winforms, mschart

I am using MS Chart control as a fast line chart to plot real-time data generated by a simulator. Every chart has up to 10 series and there can be 10 such separate charts at the most. The data is generated at a rate of about 50-100 data points at every 50-60 milliseconds that I have to plot across all the charts. Data comes all the way to the chart control in almost no time, but when it comes to `Chart.Series.Points.AddXY()`, that's where the problem starts.

I have read on SO and MSDN discussions that MS Chart invalidates after every new point addition. So I have included following code:

```
    _chart.Series[index].Points.AddXY(simTime, YValue);

    // delete more than max. points. 
    if (_chart.Series[index].Points.Count > MaxTrendPoints)
       _chart.Series[index].Points.RemoveAt(0);

    // Repaint only after adding so many points
    if (_chartUpdateCounter >= 50)
    {
       _chartUpdateCounter = 0;
       _chart.Series.ResumeUpdates();
       _chart.Series.Invalidate();
       _chart.Series.SuspendUpdates();
    }
```

to stop chart control from repainting frequently. This hasn't made any improvement at all for me.

Any pointers towards solving my issue will be very much appreciated.

Comment: SeriesChartType.FastLine or FastPoint?

Comment: Try setting `AntiAliasing` to None.

Comment: @andrei.ciprian, I am using SeriesChartType.FastLine.